# function that takes only literal integers

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to simulate certain overloaded GCC built-ins in C++.  The built-ins are similar to these:

```
__builtin_foo(char *a, signed int b);
__builtin_foo(short *a, signed int b);
__builtin_foo(long *a, signed int b);
```

With a special limitation hard coded in GCC: `b` must be a literal value, i.e. you can call:

```
__builtin_foo((char *)0, 1);
```

but not:

```
extern int val;
__builtin_foo((char *)0, val);
```

which generates a compiler error.  I've fiddled with `std::enable_if` to simulate this but cannot find a way to enforce that only literal arguments are accepted.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: #define ASSERT_LITERAL(x)  (void)(x##98765L) - causes a compile error for any non integer literal e.g. ASSERT_LITERAL(x); - fail ASSERT_LITERAL(1); - pass. Too hacky to add as an answer though

Comment: @samgak: It's also too hacky to work. `ASSERT_LITERAL(0)` will also fail.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Minor detail; `x##010L` fixes that. But I'm less sure about `ASSERT_LITERAL(0.0)`

Comment: @MikeSeymour right you are. x##76543L should work I think or anything without 8s or 9s so it can be valid octal.

Comment: @samgak: Even if it's convertible to an integer, it's not an integer itself. I'm not sure what GCC needs here.

Comment: Aren't all use cases for this covered by `constexpr`?

Comment: @samgak That ASSERT_LITERAL fails badly for `x+1` too, since the 1 binds into the new literal happily...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can sort of simulate it using a macro and the GCC intrinsic [`__builtin_constant_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp-3644)

```
constexpr int foo(int i) { return i; }

#define FOO(i) do { \
  static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(i), "Not a constant"); \
  foo(i); \
} while (false)
```

This will allow `FOO(1)` to compile, but not `int i = 1; FOO(i);`

However, the result of `__builtin_constant_p` depends on the optimisation level, at higher levels of optimisation `const` variables are treated as constants, so it doesn't only accept literals.

Of course if you're willing to allow constant-expressions, not just literals, then all you have to do is use the variable in a context that requires a constant-expression, such as a static assertion or a non-type template argument.

Comment: This looks good, I'll try that.  Actually, the builtins may also accept constants, so that would be the same as with the c++ approach, but it's really not important in the use case I have (i.e. testing whether resolution of the overloaded builtins in C works like rsolution of c++ overloaded functions).

Comment: Except that Gcc doesn't like static_assert() in a macro.  :-(

Comment: @user3510167: then use one of the historical fallbacks, like `using CHECKCONSTANT char[i];`

Comment: Finally managed to make it work with static_assert() and a Gcc extension (statement expressions):

`#define BAR(a, b) ({ static_assert((b), "failed"); bar((a), (b));})`

`extern int bar(const char *a, int b); `

`void foo(int x) `

`{`

`BAR("ok", 1); `

`BAR("error", x); `
`}`

Comment: `static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(b))`

Comment: I've chosen this approach because it does not mess with the c++ overloading rules in any way - which is what I need to test.

Answer (score 31):

Here is a portable C++11 solution so that your function (macro actually, sorry) accepts only integer literals and triggers a compile-time error instead:

```
constexpr int operator "" _literal(unsigned long long i)
{
    return i;
}

#define m_builtin_foo(integer) builtin_foo(integer ## _literal)
```

User-defined literals accept only literals (hence their name). Therefore, if you make your macro paste a user-defined literal to what is passed to it, it *should* only accept the literals accepted by the corresponding user-defined literal.

However, that's rather ugly and I guess that could be error-prone. Not sure how though.

---

@MichaelAnderson pointed in the comments that `m_builtin_foo(i+1)` would still work. That's right. @Angew suggested wrapping the return type of `_literal` in a wrapper incompatible with integer arithmetic and adding explicit conversions. He was also right, here is the more complete solution:

```
struct wrapper
{
    constexpr wrapper(int n):
        value{n}
    {}

    explicit constexpr operator int() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    int value;
};

constexpr wrapper operator "" _literal(unsigned long long i)
{
    return { int(i) };
}

#define m_builtin_foo(integer) builtin_foo(int(integer ## _literal))
```

Comment: Can even be expanded with other overloads. Clever !

Comment: What about `m_builtin_foo(x+1)`?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I believe that could be solved by having the UDL return a literal type encapsulating `i` but incompatible with integral arithmetic (perhaps with an explicit conversion to integral), and having `builtin_foo` take that type.

Answer (score 13):

You could turn the function into a template:

```
template <int b>
builtin_foo(char *a);
```

The call syntax would then be `builtin_foo<1>(whatever)`.

If you don't like this, you could wrap the template in a macro:

```
#define m_builtin_foo(a, b) builtin_foo<(b)>((a))
```

This will of course accept any integral constant expression, not just a literal.