# Overloading function calls for compile-time constants

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm interested to know whether one can distinguish between function calls using arguments provided by compile-time constants and those without?

For example:

```
int a = 2;
foo( a )  // #1: Compute at run-time
foo( 3 )  // #2: Compute at compile-time
```

Is there any way to provide overloads that distinguish between these two cases? Or more generally, how do I detect the use of a literal type?

I've looked into constexpr, but a function parameter cannot be constexpr. It would be neat to have the same calling syntax, but be able to generate different code based on the parameters being literal types or not.

Comment: If there is `constexpr int foo(int x) noexcept;` then won't `foo(3)` be computed at compile time?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008059/function-that-takes-only-literal-integers

Comment: @Arun, it will be. However, you can't tell in `foo` whether the call was made at compile time or run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the above answers somehow miss the point that the question was trying to make.

> Is there any way to provide overloads that distinguish between these two cases? Or more generally, how do I detect the use of a literal type?

this is what a 'rvalue reference' is for. literal type is a rvalue.

> It would be neat to have the same calling syntax, but be able to generate different code based on the parameters being literal types or not.

you can simply **overload** your foo() function as:

```
void foo(int&& a);
```

So when you call the function with a literal, e.g. foo(3), the compiler knows you need the above overload, as 3 is a rvalue. If you call the function as foo(a), the compiler will pick up your original version `foo(const int& a);` as `int a=2;` is a lvalue.

And this gives you the same calling syntax.

Comment: Of course, rvalues! And indeed, the point was to make overload resolution work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What about `foo(a + 3)`? Wouldn't this rvalue overload be invoked for calls like `foo(a + b)`? From the question, I was not sure that that is the requirement.

Comment: That's a good point, @Arun. I didn't think further than the examples that was given. But I wasn't sure if that is his requirement, either.

Comment: @Arun Yes, that does ultimately defeat the purpose of my question. Nevertheless, my original question didn't mention this, so given the fact that the response solves the given examples I will leave this marked as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot distinguish between a compile-time literal `int` and a run-time variable `int`. If you *need* to do this, you can provide an overload that can only work at compile-time:

```
void foo(int ); // run-time

template <int I>
void foo(std::integral_constant<int, I> ); // compile-time
```

Comment: Why go all the way to use `std::integral_constant`? You can stop at `template <int I> void foo();` for the simple use case. No?

Comment: @RSahu I just find it more convenient for some cases to already have that as an argument, so I just do it all the time. Sure, you could just do `foo<x>()`.

Answer (score -2):

In the general case you couldn't get foo(3) evaluated at compile time.  What if foo(x) was defined as add x days to the current date - and you first run the program next Tuesday?  If it really is a constant then use a symbolic constant.  If it is a simple function you could try a define (which will be replaced at compile time with the implementation -but it still will be evaluated at runtime)

e.g.

```
#define MIN(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
```

Comment: It was just a simple macro function for example - I thought the questioner was wanting a simple function substitution but he wants compile time evaluation.  My bad.