# Declare C function to accept only constant numbers

Tags: c

Is it possible to declare a function in C which allows passing only a numeric const (no variables)?

Example:

```
uint8_t gmul256(uint8_t x, uint8_t y);
```

Parameter "y" shall be accepted as numeric constant only. Variables, pointers etc. shall generate an error.

```
res = gmul256(var, 5); // -> OK
res = gmul256(var1, var2); // -> Shall generate compile error
```

Compiler is gcc.

Background: Mitigation of timing and power analysis attacks in AES code, generate more performant code.

Comment: Ah actually it is possible, with a macro :D

Comment: variables and constant both are stored in memory locations. In a binary, there exist no explicit notion of a _variable_ name, as such, it's all about memory locations.

Comment: @SouravGhosh values are not necessarily stored anywhere at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I would very much like to see such a macro, and the possible error message such a macro would lead to if passed a non-literal value. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the error would be awful. Naturally, it would work for *integer constant expressions*.

Comment: `__builtin_constant_p` can detect compile-time constants. Maybe you can make a macro that fails to compile when `__builtin_constant_p` is false

Comment: I think [this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29008202/1983495). But it's not a clear duplicate of this question IMHO, so I am not marking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your valuable input I did following:

```
#define BUILD_BUG_ON(condition) ((void)sizeof(char[1 - 2*!!(condition)]))
#define gmul256(x, y) (BUILD_BUG_ON(!__builtin_constant_p((y))), _gmul256((x), (y)))

uint8_t _gmul256(uint8_t x, uint8_t y);
```

This will generate a compile error if "y" is not a constant.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You could use `_Static_assert` on C11 instead of that hideous `BUILD_BUG_ON`... ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a macro with a bit field (C99+) to check that the argument is an *integer constant expression*. Here we declare an anonymous structure with a bitfield whose size depends on the given value. If you pass in a variable, the construct is invalid. Naturally a compiler can compile it, but a conforming compiler **must produce at least a warning**. [C11 6.7.2.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p4):

> 4. The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an **integer constant expression** with **a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted.** [122] If the value is zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.

We're using the value of `y` here to calculate the size of an anonymous structure with a bit-field, whose width depends on the value of `y`, producing either width 1 or 2 depending on the value of `y`; if `y` is not an integer constant expression, the compiler **must** report a constraint violation. As an added bonus this should work on any compiler that supports C99 bit-fields, not just GCC.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

extern int gmul256(uint8_t, uint8_t);

#define assert_int_constant(x) ((void)sizeof(struct {int dummy: 1 + !(x);}))
#define gmul256(x, y) (assert_int_constant(y), gmul256((x), (y)))

int main() {
    uint8_t x = 5, y = 42;
    gmul256(x, 5);
    gmul256(x, 5 * 5);
    gmul256(x, y);
}
```

Upon compilation would produce

```
% gcc constanttest.c
# or,  gcc constanttest.c -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra alike
constanttest.c: In function ‘main’:
constanttest.c:5:52: error: bit-field ‘dummy’ width not an integer constant
 #define assert_int_constant(x) ((void)sizeof(struct {int dummy: 1 + !(x));}))
                                                    ^
constanttest.c:6:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘assert_int_constant’
 #define gmul256(x, y) (assert_int_constant(y), gmul256((x), (y)))
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
constanttest.c:12:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘gmul256’
     gmul256(x, y);
     ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is renaming the original function necessary? I suspect `#define gmul256(x, y) (assert_int_constant(y), gmul256((x), (y)))` *should* work, and stop after first expansion.